# What is the correct behavior when there is an infinite loop between an image being max-width:100% and a container having width:min-content?

Tags: css, webkit, mozilla

I want to have an image above some text, where the width of text is determined by the image (I don't know what the dimensions of the image will be). I want it to be responsive so that the image shrinks when the screen is smaller than the image. And I want do to it in the most correct, modern way possible (no silly 2005 hacks).

My HTML would be:

```
<body>
 <div>
  <article>
   <img src="laksdjfalksdjf">
   <p>Lorem ipsum blah de blahhhhh asdfkj fasdjk</p>
  </article>
 </div>
</body>
```

And my CSS would be

```
article{width:-moz-min-content;width: -webkit-min-content;max-width:100%}
img{max-width:100%}
```

Interestingly, in Firefox this works fine. If the screen is larger than the image, the image's width is set to its normal size how it is on the server, and the width of the `article` tag is set to the same width as the image, with the text going underneath. If the image is too big for the screen, then the image and article both shrink accordingly. This is what I want, but...

In webkit browsers, the max-width attribute of the image messes with the min-content attribute of the article. Min content decides that the image's width is unknown due to the max-width attribute, and then shrinks to the longest word in the `p` tag.

I tried to read w3's docs to determine the correct behavior but I'm not used to reading those and it's really difficult for me to read.

I want to know the correct behavior so that I can use the correct one in my CSS and use a javascript workaround for the one that is wrong (that's how I like to do things).

Also, whichever one is wrong, can someone issue a bug report for me?

Fid: http://jsfiddle.net/nickmanning214/uy9pe5f6/